# VS Code - generating TODO comment when using Source action generating overriding methods

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, auto-generate

I would like to ask how can I turn off generation of TODO comments when I am using Source action generating for generiting overriding methods etc. in VS Code. See the image.
I have only Java Extension Pack and couple of more extensions that definitely should not affect this (I tried to disable them too)
[Showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ywo.png)

Comment: you have to ask at the extension that creates these texts, it is part of the Quick Action text  generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are considering this feature request. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1792) and [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2362) for more details.